# How to load a class from module(.jmod) file at runtime?

Tags: java, ide, classloader, javap

I want to load classes from a module (.jmod) file at runtime into the application memory.

I know that we can easily load classes from a (.jar) file using :-)

```
ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{
                jarFile.toURL()
            });
```

The total code snippet can be found at [this-repo](https://github.com/omegaui/omegaide-better-deassembler) in src **omega.deassembler.JarLoader** class

But the problem is URLClassLoader is unable to read the modules(.jmod).

So is there any other internal class or library to load classes from a module(.jmod) file.

Actually, I am creating an IDE and this-repo is a part of it for loading content-assist hints.

Earlier, I was using **javap** command to disassemble and load hints (see [omegaide on github](https://github.com/omegaui/omegaide)).

But this technique consumes much time, so i am writing it again!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is not exactly the answer but a method to make `URLClassLoader` usable when it has to read modules.

Earlier URLClassLoader was throwing this exception when trying to read a module file(.jmod)

when **omitting** the module-info

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/event/DirectEvent (wrong name: classes/com/sun/javafx/event/DirectEvent)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    etc
```

and when **including** the meta-info

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: classes/module-info is not a class because access_flag ACC_MODULE is set
```

This means that it is **unable to identify the directory system inside the jmod file**.

So as we know, that a simple jar file contains classes and resources only (Just exclude meta-info).

And in a module file(.jmod), all the classes are placed inside the **classes** folder and all the resources are placed in the **resources** folder.

Thus, We can create a **temporary jar** file say "modular-jar.jar" with the contents of classes and resources from the module file,

and then using standard URLClassLoader we can load it onto the classpath

and then can **immediately delete the file**.

**This will just work at least in my case**

Here's the code snippet

```
public static synchronized JarLoader prepareModule(String modulePath){
        try{
            ZipFile moduleFile = new ZipFile(modulePath);
            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("readable-module-data.jar"));
            for(Enumeration enums = moduleFile.entries(); enums.hasMoreElements();){
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)enums.nextElement();
                String name = entry.getName();
                if((name.startsWith("classes") && !name.contains("module-info")) || name.startsWith("resources")){
                         zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name.substring(name.indexOf('/') + 1)));
                         InputStream in = moduleFile.getInputStream(entry);
                         while(in.available() > 0)
                              zipOutputStream.write(in.read());
                         zipOutputStream.flush();
                }
            }
              zipOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new JarLoader("readable-module-data.jar");
}
```